# gmail api client side authentication php

Tags: php, gmail, gmail-api

i'm using a guide on gmail site but i don't understand in witch way i can send back the autorization from google to my application :

if i use this code on a guide (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php ) i need to put inside my application the authcode after i went on a google auth page:

```
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($authUrl, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    $accessToken = $client->authenticate(AUTORIZATIONCODE);
```

and using this sistem the authcode work all time i want (i use this sistem 2 weeks ago and i don't need to relogin)

there is a method to put the auth inside the application with out copy the code using copy/paste? and save this code temporay ( 1 day ? 1 week?)

(i create OAuth 2.0 client ID Credentials on google develope is correct ?)

**UPDATE!!!**

if you need to  create an autorizationcode using just a consent screen you need to this step:

1- create  a Web application Credential

2- add in this credential the redirect page

3- and change this line inside page this :

```
$accessToken = $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
```

(the expiration time is 3600 )

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking. If you want sensitive information like your clientID not stored in your code, you can reference a file which contains it? If you want to remain "signed in", a refresh token handles that. They generally shouldn't expire, but it _can_ happen, which is why you need to check and relogin if it does occur. The PHP quickstart would have all that you need.

Comment: the problem is when you check the credetian the quickstart create automaticaly a json with a data and i think is not correct because i store indefinitily the guest data  and with that credential i can go inside of the gmail when i want. there isn't a solution that i force the client to log in every time? (not just only delete myself the file)